# Why I get only 50 items by python-amazon-product-api.AmazonAPI.search

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I am using https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api.
Each time the number of returned items is 50, even if I used search_n(100, ...). Anybody knows why? Where to set the maximum number? Thanks

```
    amazon = AmazonAPI('key',
            'key2',
            'key3',
            MaxQPS=0.9,
            Region='US')
    try:
            products = amazon.search_n(100, Keywords='drone', SearchIndex='All')
            for i, product in enumerate(products):
                 print_statement


    except Exception as e:
            print "Exception while searching Amazon:"+str(e)
```

Comment: The docs at https://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ don't reference a `search_n` method -- are you sure you aren't using https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api , which does?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Already updated. https://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ can return more than 50 items each time?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) about ItemPage parameter:

> Valid values: 1 to 10 (1 to 5 when search index is All)

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem, and it seems to be because Amazon restricts the number of pages to 10. So you can get a maximum of 100 products. You can try to refine the search to be more precise, and then you might narrow the search and obtain more products you're really interested in.

The search you're making there is too broad. Try to change it to something like:

```
products = amazon.search(Keywords='Drone', Title='Drone', SearchIndex='Electronics')
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the maximum number of returned page [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PagingandSortingThroughResults.html#MaximumNumberofPages).
The Maximum Page Number of ItemLookup operation is 150 and of ItemSearch is 10 pages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.